# How do I send an event to Azure IoT Hub via HTTPS

Tags: azure, iot

I setup an IoT hub on Azure, and created a device called "ServerTemp".  I generated an SAS token, and it seems to be accepted (I don't get 401).  But I'm getting a 400 Bad Request.

Here is the request I'm sending via curl:

`curl -v -H"Authorization:SharedAccessSignature sr=A794683.azure-devices.net&sig=<snip>" -H"Content-Type:application/json" -d'{"deviceId":"ServerTemp","temperature":70}' https://A479683.azure-devices.net/devices/ServerTemp/messages/events?api-version=2016-11-14`

Request and Response (output from curl):

```
> POST /devices/ServerTemp/messages/events?api-version=2016-11-14 HTTP/1.1
> Host: A479683.azure-devices.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization:SharedAccessSignature sr=A794683.azure-devices.net&sig=<snip>
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 42
>
* upload completely sent off: 42 out of 42 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Length: 151
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
< iothub-errorcode: ArgumentInvalid
< Date: Sun, 15 Apr 2018 22:21:50 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host A479683.azure-devices.net left intact
{"Message":"ErrorCode:ArgumentInvalid;BadRequest","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:963189cb515345e69f94300655d3ca23-G:10-TimeStamp:04/15/2018 22:21:50"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add the expiry time `&se=` (as in `&se=1555372034`) when you form the SAS. It should be the very last parameter. That's the only way i can reproduce the HTTP 400 you're seeing (by omitting it). You should get a `204 No Content` once you fix that.

The resource (`&sr=`) part also seems a bit off in your case, there's no device being specified. Use [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/releases/tag/2018-3-13) to generate a *device* SAS (or just to see how it should look like): *Management > SAS Token*.

[SAS structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#security-token-structure) —
`SharedAccessSignature sig={signature-string}&se={expiry}&skn={policyName}&sr={URL-encoded-resourceURI}`

```
$ curl -i https://poorlyfundedskynet.azure-devices.net/devices/dexter/messages/events?api-version=2016-11-14 \
    -H "Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=poorlyfundedskynet.azure-devices.net%2fdevices%2fdexter&sig=RxxxxxxxtE%3d&se=1555372034" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d'{"deviceId":"dexter","temperature":70}'

  HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
  Content-Length: 0
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Date: Sun, 15 Apr 2018 23:54:25 GMT
```

You can monitor ingress with [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/releases/tag/2018-3-13) or [iothub-explorer](https://github.com/Azure/iothub-explorer):

[image: Device Explorer Monitor]

Probably this would work as well: [Azure IoT Extension for Azure CLI 2.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-cli-extension)

Comment: Thanks! Using Device Explorer to generate an SAS did the trick. I was using the example python script, and I must have been doing something wrong.